# Get all cryptocurrencies github repositories on coingecko API

Tags: github, cryptocurrency, coingecko

How can I get all cryptocurrencies github main accounts (where there is one) ?

This information should be able with Coingecko API, as for instance we can see [here](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/bitcoin) a line called source code giving the address of the bitcoin github repository.

I want to get the githubs using [coingecko API](https://www.coingecko.com/api/) for all cryptocurrencies but I did not find any information for that in the [documentation](https://www.coingecko.com/api/documentations/v3).

Is there an option to get this information from this API ? Or is there another free API for getting this information if this is not possible on coingecko ?

Any help would be great !

Answer (score 0):

You can get the repo URLs in the coin detail endpoint (`GET /coins/{id}`, [docs](https://www.coingecko.com/api/documentations/v3#/operations/coins/get_coins__id_)), property `links.repos_url`.

Example:

https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin

```
{
  "id": "bitcoin",
  ...
  "links": {
      ...
      "repos_url": {
        "github": [
          "https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin",
          "https://github.com/bitcoin/bips"
        ],
        "bitbucket": []
      }
  }
}
```